# Save button missing from content type edit form

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

Here is what the bottom of my "leaflet" content type edit form (i.e. admin > structure > content types > leaflet > edit) looks like:
[image: Leaflet content type edit form]

Here is what the bottom of my "testimony" content type edit form looks like:
[image]

Note that there are no save/delete buttons! Another of my content types has also now picked up this bug. This just happened. I have no idea why. I can't save changes! I tried flushing all caches and it didn't help. I'm an administrator and I have permissions for everything.

Why would this have happened and what can I do? Drupal 7.19.

Comment: Try disabling Diff, i18n and other modules that might be altering this form (modules that likely adding new elements to this form). there could be a module altering the form improperly.

Comment: Check in your content type, you probably selected require preview before publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the i18n synchronize translations module. Disabling it fixed the problem. Of I have to immediately re-enable it afterwards since I actually use this module. So I filed an issue: http://drupal.org/node/2004260. Thanks to Ayesh K who gave me the idea in his comment on my question. Since it's not an answer I can't mark it correct, so I'm just answering here and will mark this correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an odd one, some form_alter or theme issue.

If you try a good admin theme like

- [Tao](http://drupal.org/project/tao) ( base admin theme )
- [Rubik](http://drupal.org/project/rubik) ( admin theme )

Download both, enable and set admin theme in

- /admin/appearance
- ADMINISTRATION THEME
  Choose "Default theme" to always use the same theme as the rest of the site. ( RUBIK )
- Use the administration theme when editing or creating content ( CHECK )

The buttons should show up again