# Save button missing on User Account Edit form

Tags: forms, users

I have months old problem of missing "Save" button on the user account edit form. Which is annoying to the point that now I have to find the solution.

I don't usually use account edit form since there is only one user. I have updated many modules and different cores but problem always remained there. Right now I am running latest core which is 7.23. And all modules are updated. This is a multilingual website.

Since this problem has appeared I am unable to save any change in any user account. Please have a look on the image attached.
Please help.

Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: right click and click on the inspect element and see the properties for submit button exists ?

Comment: Thanks @harshal for input. I have checked the html of the user account edit form. I have not found the div for the save button. Which is simply not generated. Have a look [http://i.imgur.com/yafZGjA.jpg]

Comment: What do you mean by "there is only one user"? You have several roles and Masquerade module and you also say "I am unable to save any changes in *any* user account".

Comment: @KariKääriäinen Previously I had some dummy accounts from the beginning of the project which I deleted later on. They also did not have save button on their account edit form.

Comment: What else could this be than a bug in some of the contrib modules? I was looking into ways of printing the form state at all relevant hooks by hacking core, but didn't come up with anything practical. Looks like you're gonna have to just disable modules until you get your button back. I would try to use some kind of a forking scheme, disable first half, then half of the rest etc. Maybe make a copy of the site file system and database or take a backup and restore that later.

Comment: Hi @KariKääriäinen, You are right. Same solution is suggested by another Drupal developer at drupal.org: https://drupal.org/node/2089549

Comment: Since the core and contrib modules are giving some other annoying problems as well, which I could not solve. And the site does not have a complex structure. I have decided to create a new version on a fresh install and import only data from old site to the new one, leaving the bad code behind. Besides this I have now created Aegir hosting which will help me say good bye to shared hosting altogether.

Comment: Why don't you just try disabling modules? Would be interesting and useful to everyone to find out if the culprit was some module.

Comment: For the sake of knowledge, yes, I will try disabling method and report back here. 
Fingers crossed if this could solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling i18n synchronization module.

There is another question similar to yours. [Save button missing from content type edit form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58932/save-button-missing-from-content-type-edit-form)
Problem: save button missing from content type edit form. Reason: bug in i18n synchronization module. Solution: none here, but...

There is another case where i18n synchronization causes an infinite loop and there is patch along the lines of

```
if (function_exists(i18n_sync)) i18n_sync(FALSE);
```

This is the link, the patch is at #3. https://drupal.org/node/1372500
Maybe that will help you to the right direction.

Comment: thanks for very useful points. I have read these posts before. I have disabled i18n synchronization module, cleared the caches ran update.. still no Save button on the account Edit form..

Comment: Can you create a non-admin user and see if it has the same problem?

Comment: yes, I have created non admin accounts and still no luck. thanks for help.